# No internet connection when building image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created a custom configuration for docker daemon, here is the config

```
{
        "bip" : "192.168.1.32/24",
        "default-address-pools" : [
                {
                        "base" : "172.16.200.0/24",
                        "size" : 24
                },
                {
                        "base" : "172.16.25.0/24",
                        "size" : 24
                }
        ],
        "debug" : true,
        "hosts" : ["tcp://127.0.0.69:4269", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"],
        "default-gateway" : "192.168.1.1",
        "dns" : ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"],
        "experimental" : true,
        "log-driver" : "json-file",
        "log-opts" : {
                "max-size" : "20m",
                "max-file" : "3",
                "labels" : "develope_status",
                "env" : "developing"
        }                
}
```

`bip` is my host IP address and `default-gateway` is my router gateway
, I created 2 address pools so it can assign IP address to the container
But during the build process, the image has no internet so it can't do `apk update`.
Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
        blog:
                build: ./
                image: blog:1.0
                ports:
                        - "456:80"
                        - "450:443"
                volumes:
                        - .:/blog
                        - ./logs:/var/log/apache2
                        - ./httpd-ssl.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
                container_name: blog
                hostname: alpine
                command: apk update

networks:
        default:
                external: 
                        name: vpc
```

Here is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM httpd:2.4-alpine

ENV REFRESHED_AT=2021-02-01 \
APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data \
APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data \
APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2 \
APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2.pid \
APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2 \
APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2

RUN mkdir -p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR \ 
&& sed -i \
        -e 's/^#\(Include .*httpd-ssl.conf\)/\1/' \
        -e 's/^#\(LoadModule .*mod_ssl.so\)/\1/' \
        -e 's/^#\(LoadModule .*mod_socache_shmcb.so\)/\1/' \
        conf/httpd.conf \
&& echo "Include /blog/blog.conf" >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
VOLUME ["/blog", "$APACHE_LOG_DIR"]
EXPOSE 80 443
```

The running container was able to ping google and do apk update like normal but if I put `RUN apk update` inside the dockerfile it won't update.

Any help would be great, thank you

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any of that manual Docker configuration at all (the `hosts` setting opens a major security issue especially).  If you go back to the default settings, do things work as you expect?

Comment: Yeah you right mate, maybe I should have just stick with the default setting anyway but thanks for the info, Cheer!